# how does one parse the query parameters when using UriMatcher together with a ConentProvider

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider

I have a ConentProvider and make use of a UriMatcher to perform the appropriate
SQL statements.

The code works but I do not like the way I extract the parameters from
the uri's:

THIS IS FAILING:

```
String badge_id = uri.getQueryParameter("id");
String badge_value = uri.getQueryParameter("badge");
```

, and would have been ideal.

**What is the correct/optimal way to get the parameters and have
my uri matcher working?**

THE CALL:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://" + USERSSchema.AUTHORITY
+ "/" + USERSSchema.USERSTable.TABLE_USERS + "/id/" + String.valueOf(badgeId) + "/badge/" + String.valueOf(badgeValue));

getApplication().getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().update(uri,null,null,null);
```

THE RECEIVER:

```
    private static final int USERS_UPDATE_ORDER_BY_ID = 1;
    private static final int USERS_CHANGE_ORDER_BY_ORDER = 2;
    private static final int USERS_CHANGE_BADGE = 3; 


uriMatcher.addURI(USERSSchema.AUTHORITY,USERSSchema.USERSTable.TABLE_USERS 
        + "/from_id/#/to_id/#", USERS_UPDATE_ORDER_BY_ID);



uriMatcher.addURI(USERSSchema.AUTHORITY,USERSSchema.USERSTable.TABLE_USERS 
            + "/from_order/#/to_order/#", USERS_CHANGE_ORDER_BY_ORDER);


uriMatcher.addURI(USERSSchema.AUTHORITY,USERSSchema.USERSTable.TABLE_USERS 
            + "/id/#/badge/#", USERS_CHANGE_BADGE);



@Override
public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues contentValues, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {

              switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)) {

                   case USERS_UPDATE_ORDER_BY_ID :
                        // ....
                        break:

                   case USERS_CHANGE_ORDER_BY_ORDER:
                        // ....
                        break;
                   case USERS_CHANGE_BADGE :

                        String badge_id = uri.getQueryParameter("id");
                        String badge_value = uri.getQueryParameter("badge");

                        **//WHAT IS THE BETTER WAY?** 
                        int badge_segment = 0;
                        for (String segment : uri.getPathSegments()) {
                            switch (badge_segment++) {
                                case  2 :
                                  badge_id = segment;
                                  break;
                                case 4 :
                                  badge_value = segment;
                                  break;
                            }
                        }

                    break;
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're confusing query parameters in the traditional sense, with the way frameworks like Symfony handle them.

Uri.getQueryParameter looks for the query string (content://demo?key=value). To get parameters from inside the path, use Uri.getPathSegments().